# How to add role globally in Hasura?

Tags: hasura

Does anyone know how to add a new role globally in Hasura?

e.g. an `editor` role

Someone had set this up on a project I worked on in the past, and I'm curious how to do it.

I need it so any time I add a new table, for the `editor` role to be automatically show up in the Permissions tab.

Currently I have to go in and add it every time for each new table.

Comment: What version of Hasura are you using? Is this on the hosted cloud offering or are you self hosting?

Normally as soon as you add a new role on any table it automatically starts showing up in all of the other ones

Comment: Thank you. I will give that a try. Using the cloud version.